# Linear textures look as if they are sampled nearest when quad is small, but linearly when large?

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I have a sprite of size 222x372 pixels and am rendering it at 3 different scales (25%, 40%, and 65%) to test the different sampling options.

If I use `GL_NEAREST` the texture looks pixelated unless scaled to specific ratios. (as expected)

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

If I use `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR` the texture looks blurry when small, and crisp when large. If I use other mipmap combinations, similar occurs with either blurry, pixelated, or both. (as expected)

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR); // Blurry
OR
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR); // Pixelated
OR
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST); // Blurry
```

If I use `GL_LINEAR` the texture looks crisp when large but, to my surprise, pixelated and almost identical to `GL_NEAREST` when small.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR); // When small, pixelated?
```

See this image:

[image: See this image]

See `GL_LINEAR` at 25% scale - you can see the aliasing and pixelated edges. I was expecting linear interpolation to smoothly blend these edges.

Is this intended behavior, and if so is there any way to get crisp sprites even when scaled down to small amounts? Custom mipmap levels generated in Photoshop perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this intended behavior,

Yes. With `GL_LINEAR` the filter footprint is always `2x2` texels. If you scale down by 50%, your *pixel* footprint is also 2x2 texels, so it still works reasonably well (besides the actual size of the pixel footprint, it's exact position within the texel grid is relevant, too, but let's ignore that for simplicity here).

If you scale down to 25%, it means that the area worth 4x4 texels is mapped to a single pixel on the screen - but the filter will  use only the 2x2 block in the midlle of that. So out of the 16 texel values which are mapped to the screen, only 4 are used, and the content of the other 12 is completely ignored - so if you have high frequency data like fine details and sharp edges, the downsampling will result in a lot of aliasing. Downsampling is a lowpass filter after all, and high-frequency content doesn't survive this well.

Mipmapping is the intented solution for this kind of problems. Instead of having to filter a varying - and potentially huge number of pixels (e.g. if you map a 1024x1024 texture a single pixel, the filter would have to walk through over 1 Million pixels!) at sample time, those operations are already pre-calcuated. A texel at mipmap level 1 represents 2x2 texels of level 0, and one at level 2 represents 4x4 of level 0, and so on.

> and if so is there any way to get crisp sprites even when scaled down to small amounts? Custom mipmap levels generated in Photoshop perhaps?

Custom mipmap images might certainly help a bit in your scenario - but the ultimate question is: what do you expect? If you have image content with thin black lines and fine details at 100% scale, there is *no* way to preserve that at a significant lower resolution, so the result is always bound to either look a bit blurry (because all the fine details which now fall into a single pixel are somehow mixed together), or it will look pixelated (because only some of the details which fall into the pixel are used to represent the whole pixel) - the Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem holds true in this case as in every other.